# I SVN updated, but I realize I messed up

Tags: linux, svn, unix

How do I rollback to a previous revision? So that my files are back to revision 400?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

`svn merge -r [current_version]:[previous_version] [repository_url]`

`svn commit -m “Reverting previous commit and going back to revision [previous_version].”`

taken from http://mybravenewworld.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/subversion-how-to-revert-a-bad-commit/

Comment: This is correct, but I would add that while the contents of the file are back to what they were in revision 400, the new revision number will be at least 402--there is no true rollback.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn update -r 400
```

Comment: And then do I commit everything again?

Comment: see new answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445937/i-svn-updated-but-i-realize-i-messed-up/2446065#2446065

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
svn -r rev-no up file-name
```